# Expectation and variance of a sum of two random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, variance

Following up on this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19948/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-sum-of-non-i-i-d-gaussian-variates), how would you derive the expectation and variance of the sum of two normally distributed random variables that aren't necessarily independent?

For example, if $$X \sim N(\mu, 3\sigma^2)$$ and $$Y \sim N(\mu + 9, \sigma^2)$$ is there a way to calculate the expectation and variance? What would the resulting X + Y distribution be in concrete terms? We aren't given the covariance.

Comment: If they aren't independent, then you would need to know how they depend on each other in order to compute the desired quantities, no?

Comment: Independence is not necessary for the expectation. The expectation is a linear operator.

Comment: You need to know the covariance, then https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464219/variance-of-combination-of-random-variables-not-independent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variance of combination of random variables (not independent)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464219/variance-of-combination-of-random-variables-not-independent)

Comment: I also thought you would need covariance to calculate variance given only distributions, but covariance isn't given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=\mu+\mu+9=2 \mu +9$$
$$\begin{array}
 VVar[X+Y]&=Var[X]+Var[Y]+2Cov[X,Y]\\
&=3 \sigma^2+\sigma^2+E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]\\
&=4 \sigma^2+E[XY]-\mu(\mu+9)
\end{array}$$

We can't say that much about the distribution of $XY$ without some more assumptions. If we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $XY$ has a chi-squared distribution and we can compute $E[XY]$.

Comment: +1, However, if we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ or equivalently, $Cov(X,Y) = 0$. No need to use the chi-square relationship here.

Comment: In other words, the variance would just be $4\sigma^2$?

Comment: Yes, if your independent then $Cov[X,Y]=0$.